# Initialize variable from LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a game in which you click a potato and you get potatoes to buy boosts with (like cookieclicker). I'm using localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.getItem() to save the amount of potatoes the player has, and this code works fine:

```
var potatoes = 0;

function addPotato(amount)
{
    potatoes += amount;
    localStorage.setItem('potatoes', potatoes);

    if ( localStorage.getItem('potatoes') ) {
        document.getElementById("potatoes").innerHTML = "<b>Potatoes: </b>" + localStorage.getItem('potatoes'); 
    }
}
```

but my problem is that it wont stay after I reload the page (since `var potatoes` is set to 0).
I have tried changing it to

```
var potatoes = 0;

if ( localStorage.getItem('potatoes') ) {
    potatoes = localStorage.getItem('potatoes'); 
}
```

but that for some strange reason makes the number of potatoes be appended to the paragraph instead of overwriting it, so if I click the potato 5 times instead of saying 5 it says 11111. And yes, I know the player could change the variable locally but that doesen't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the item from localStorage, it's a string - do a parseInt on that value to convert it back to an integer:

```
potatoes = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('potatoes'), 10);
```

Comment: Thank you, and may I ask what the 10 does?

Comment: It interprets the number as a decimal. You can use 8 for octal, 2 for binary and so on

Comment: @Miro If you do not know, the radix `10` at the end is important, so Javascript knows it is decimal, not octal!

Comment: Okay, can't accept your answer until 7 minutes, but thanks, really useful.

Answer (score 2):

localStorage stores everything as strings.  ParseInt it